# How to return a value from CLGeocoder?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I'm working on the weather app as a training and there's a need to convert location to city. So I'm using CLGeocoder like so:

```
 func updateWeatherData(json: JSON?) {

        if let json = json {
            weatherData.temperature = fahrenheitToCelcius(json["currently"]["temperature"].doubleValue)
            weatherData.weatherIconName = json["currently"]["icon"].stringValue

            let location = CLLocation(latitude: json["latitude"].doubleValue, longitude: json["longitude"].doubleValue)
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in

                if let city = placemark {
                    self.weatherData.city = city.last?.locality
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            updateUIWithWeatherData()
        }

    }
    //MARK: - UI Updates

    func updateUIWithWeatherData() {

        cityLabel.text = weatherData.city
        temperatureLabel.text = "\(weatherData.temperature)°"
        weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: weatherData.weatherIconName!)

    }
```

And this code returns nil to weatherData.city. But when I place a breakpoint inside a closure, everything works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: call `updateUIWithWeatherData()` from inside closure. Its happening coz `reverseGeocode` is called asynchronously and `updateUIWithWeatherData` is being called before the response

Comment: You are missing an important part: It's asynchrone. `updateUIWithWeatherData()` will be called BEFORE `if let city = placemark` is done. So put `updateUIWithWeatherData()` INSIDE the closure (and do that call in main thread because it's UI related and the closure might be done in a background thread).

Comment: That magically solves it. Thank you!

Comment: @MaxKraev Magically? Are you seriously having trouble understanding this?

Comment: @MaticOblak I'm really new to iOS development and was not aware about threading, but now I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly you need to update your UI after the geocoding is complete. Like the following:

```
func updateWeatherData(json: JSON?) {

    if let json = json {
        weatherData.temperature = fahrenheitToCelcius(json["currently"]["temperature"].doubleValue)
        weatherData.weatherIconName = json["currently"]["icon"].stringValue

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: json["latitude"].doubleValue, longitude: json["longitude"].doubleValue)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in

            if let city = placemark {
                self.weatherData.city = city.last?.locality
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            self.updateUIWithWeatherData()
        }            
    }

}
```

The order of these operations is so that the geocoding is done asynchronously and may occur later then the code called after it. Note *may* but does not need to.

You should also read documentation of this method about threading. UI must be updated on main thread so unless the documentation specifies that the call will be done on main thread you are best forcing it:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemark, error) in    
    if let city = placemark {
        self.weatherData.city = city.last?.locality
    } else if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.updateUIWithWeatherData()
    }
}
```